# Is there a way to display a personalised list for a user in ASP.NET when they login

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

I am creating a system for teachers and students where when a teacher logs in to the system, a list of the members in their class appears... however I have no idea how to do this. Does anyone have any advice on how to go about this?

Comment: You have to add some clarifications. Is the teacher confined to one class or she has to teach different courses to multiple classes?

Comment: Teacher is confined to one class... there is a student model, teacher model and cohort model to connect the two

Comment: Is the cohort the class in this case?

Comment: yes the cohort represents the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a teacher is confined to one class, a one to one relationship between a teacher and the class is created.

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public Cohort Cohort {get; set;}
    public int CohortId {get; set;}
}
```

The cohort or the class can have many students.

```
public class Cohort
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int TeacherId {get; set;}
    public Teacher Teacher {get; set;}
    public List<Student> Students{get; set;}
}
```

The student can only belong to one cohort.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public Cohort Cohort {get; set;}
    public int CohortId {get; set;}
}
```

**UPDATE**
Retrieve the students of a teacher by:

```
var cohort = _context.Cohorts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.TeacherId == YourTeacherId);
var students = _context.Students.Where(s => s.CohortId == cohort.Id);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is how I have it set up. My confusion now lies with creating my controllers and views and ensuring that when a teacher logs in to the index, they can only see their students in a list. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated the answer to retrieve students of a teacher

Comment: My apologies for being so slow with this but I have this in my service layer  public 
        public List<Student>GetStudentsForTeacher(int userId)
        {
            var studentlist = ctx.Students.Where(s => s.Cohort.Teacher.User.Id == userId).ToList();
            return studentlist;
        }
this is my controller, // GET /students
        public IActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            var studentlist = svc.GetStudentsForTeacher(id);
            return View(studentlist);
        } 
but i have no idea how to then display on the cshtml page

Comment: @culdaffe You just loop through the studentlist in the view then display each? Or is there something I'm missing

Comment: Thank you so much for your help... I had the method for calling the students completely wrong and you solved my problem. Thank you so much! Lifesaver